# How to pass array data from controller to the view in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass data from my controller to my view

I'm working with MVC methods and I implemented OOP in my project

My controller TestController.class.php :

```
class TestController{

    public function testEditionAction(){
        $test = new test(); <-- instantiate my model which inherit DB class where I manipulate my datas
        $allTest = $test->retrieveAllTest(); <-- lietterally select * from test and return result into $allTest

        $myView = new View("test-accueil"); <-- load my view test-accueil.php
    }
}
```

Extract of my view test-accueil.php:

```
<div class="body_wrapper">
        <table>
            <?php foreach($allTest as $key => $value): ?>   
                <tr class="tr_wrapper">
                    <td class="td_center wrapper_img">
                        <img class="logo_langage" src="../../images/<?php echo $value->langage; ?>_logo.png">
                    </td>
                    ...
                    ...
```

here's print_r($allTest) return :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [0] => 1
            [langage] => python
            [1] => python
            [level] => 3
            [2] => 3
            [Name_test] => Afficher toute les cartes d'un jeu
            [3] => Afficher toute les cartes d'un jeu
            [description] => <p>Affichage d'un jeu de carte en programmation (Python)</p>
            [4] => <p>Affichage d'un jeu de carte en programmation (Python)</p>
            [Test_excercice] => <p>ceci est l'&eacute;nonc&eacute; pour l'exercice 2</p>
            [5] => <p>ceci est l'&eacute;nonc&eacute; pour l'exercice 2</p>
            [Test_answer] => <p>1 de Coeur 1 de Carreau 1 de Pique 1 de Trefle 2 de Coeur 2 de Carreau 2 de Pique 2 de Trefle 3 de Coeur 3 de Carreau 3 de Pique 3 de Trefle 4 de Coeur 4 de Carreau 4 de Pique 4 de Trefle 5 de Coeur 5 de Carreau 5 de Pique 5 de Trefle 6 de Coeur 6 de Carreau 6 de Pique 6 de Trefle 7 de Coeur 7 de Carreau 7 de Pique 7 de Trefle 8 de Coeur 8 de Carreau 8 de Pique 8 de Trefle 9 de Coeur 9 de Carreau 9 de Pique 9 de Trefle 10 de Coeur 10 de Carreau 10 de Pique 10 de Trefle de Coeur V de Carreau V de Pique V de Trefle D de Coeur D de Carreau D de Pique D de Trefle R de Coeur R de Carreau R de Pique R de Trefle</p>
            [6] => <p>1 de Coeur 1 de Carreau 1 de Pique 1 de Trefle 2 de Coeur 2 de Carreau 2 de Pique 2 de Trefle 3 de Coeur 3 de Carreau 3 de Pique 3 de Trefle 4 de Coeur 4 de Carreau 4 de Pique 4 de Trefle 5 de Coeur 5 de Carreau 5 de Pique 5 de Trefle 6 de Coeur 6 de Carreau 6 de Pique 6 de Trefle 7 de Coeur 7 de Carreau 7 de Pique 7 de Trefle 8 de Coeur 8 de Carreau 8 de Pique 8 de Trefle 9 de Coeur 9 de Carreau 9 de Pique 9 de Trefle 10 de Coeur 10 de Carreau 10 de Pique 10 de Trefle de Coeur V de Carreau V de Pique V de Trefle D de Coeur D de Carreau D de Pique D de Trefle R de Coeur R de Carreau R de Pique R de Trefle</p>
            [Test_instruction] => <p>Ceci est les instructions pour l'EXCERCIE 2</p>
            [7] => <p>Ceci est les instructions pour l'EXCERCIE 2</p>
            [Test_start_code] => <p>#!/usr/bin/python3 # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*- # Initialisation du jeu de cartes</p>
            [8] => <p>#!/usr/bin/python3 # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*- # Initialisation du jeu de cartes</p>
            [prev_rh] => <p>prev rh test</p>
            [9] => <p>prev rh test</p>
            [grand_theme] => grand theme test
            [10] => grand theme test
            [tps_est] => 5 min
            [11] => 5 min
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
          ...
          ...
        )
```

I tried to use `include controller/TestController.class.php` in the header of view file but it say fatal error can't declare new class because it's already define in `TestController.class.php`

Comment: One way: In your controller set `$this->allTest` = $allTest;` and always instantiate your views with an instance of the controller, e.g. `new View("test-accueil", $this);`. Then your view can get the data from the passed controller instance.

Comment: I tried it and it works, thanks.